# writing string text pyramid pattern in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I am new to android and trying to write this pyramid in java but it is not printing exactly.

i want to print like this
[image]

**my code to write this is**

```
  String searchQuery = "rooms in mumbai";

    int n = searchQuery.length();

    for (int i = 0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<=i-1; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(searchQuery.charAt(j));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

**but this printing this**

```
r
ro
roo
room
rooms
rooms 
rooms i
rooms in
rooms in 
rooms in m
rooms in mu
rooms in mum
rooms in mumb
rooms in mumba
rooms in mumbai
```

As we can see it is priting some lines two times and I want the print to start from "roo" but it is printing from "r". Guide me how can i do that

Comment: It is NOT printing some lines twice.  The "second" line has a blank space at the end, which is in your input string.  Note lines [1] and [2] in your example.  If you changed your code to add starting and ending delimiters to the output you would see this.

Comment: thank you for response i just want to print something like above in the image how can i do that??

Comment: You already are.  Your code works.

Comment: yes it is working but how to avoid repetition of words like rooms roms, rooms in rooms in

Comment: @VivekMFauzdar in your own example, it prints `wout` and `wout ` so it is the same behaviour

Comment: ohhh but is there no way to avoid that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start printing from `roo` instead of `r`, change the outer loop

```
for (int i = 0; i<=n; i++)
```

into

```
for (int i = 3; i<=n; i++)
```

If you want to avoid/skip  , just add this line after `System.out.println()`

```
if (j + 1 < n && searchQuery.charAt(j+1).equals(" ")){
    i++;
}
```

This will effectively skip printing new lines that simply have an extra space compared to the previous line

Comment: hey can you please guide me how can i print this pattern in my firebase databse android java

Answer (score 1):

**BE SIMPLE!!!**

```java
String str = "rooms in mumbai";

for (int i = 3; i <= str.length(); i++)
    if (str.charAt(i) != ' ')
        System.out.println(str.substring(0, i));
```

**Output:**

```
roo
room
rooms 
rooms i
rooms in 
rooms in m
rooms in mu
rooms in mum
rooms in mumb
rooms in mumba
rooms in mumbai
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it start from `roo` just simply make `int i = 3`

Comment: happy to here that